How to prevent Shadcn Sheet closing when there is zod from error in next.js 14
The sheet closes upon submission even when there's an error. I'm unsure where to place the error trap in the code to prevent the sheet from closing.
I found a post to prevent that from happening
Prevent closing of shadcn Sheet component based on a certain condition
When I change the suggested tag from
 <Sheet onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
to
 <Sheet open={isOpen} onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
I am not able to close the sheet using top close or Cancel button
cellaction.txs
"use client";

import { CategoryForm } from "@/components/forms/category-form";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import { Sheet, SheetTrigger } from "@/components/ui/sheet"
import { Category } from "@/constants/data";
import { Edit, MoreHorizontal, Trash } from "lucide-react";
import { useState } from "react";

interface CellActionProps {
  data: Category;
}
export const CellAction: React.FC<CellActionProps> = ({ data }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Sheet onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
        <DropdownMenu modal={false}>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
              <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
              <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
            </DropdownMenuTrigger>
            <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
              <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
              <DropdownMenuItem>
                <SheetTrigger>
                  <div className="flex"><Edit className="mr-2 h-4 w-4"/>Edit</div>
                </SheetTrigger>
              </DropdownMenuItem>
              <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                <Trash className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Delete
              </DropdownMenuItem>
            </DropdownMenuContent>
          </DropdownMenu>

          <CategoryForm initialData={data} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen}/>
      </Sheet>
    </>
  );
};


category-form.tsx

"use client";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useState } from "react";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Form, FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage, } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";
import { useToast } from "../ui/use-toast";
import { SheetContent, SheetDescription, SheetHeader, SheetFooter, SheetTitle, SheetTrigger, SheetClose, } from "@/components/ui/sheet"
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z
    .string()
    .min(3, { message: "Category Name must be at least 3 characters" }),
  status: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please select a Status" }),
});

type CategoryFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

interface CategoryFormProps {
  initialData: any | null;
  isOpen: boolean;
  setIsOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

export const CategoryForm: React.FC<CategoryFormProps> = ({
  initialData,
  setIsOpen,
  isOpen
}) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const title = initialData ? "Edit product" : "Create product";
  const description = initialData ? "Edit a product." : "Add a new product";
  const toastMessage = initialData ? "Product updated." : "Product created.";
  const action = initialData ? "Save changes" : "Create";
  
  const defaultValues = initialData
    ? initialData
    : {
        name: "",
        status: "",
      };
  
  const form = useForm<CategoryFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: CategoryFormValues, changeSetIsOpen: any) => {

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      if (initialData) {
        // await axios.post(`/api/categories/${initialData._id}`, data);
      } else {
        // const res = await axios.post(`/api/products/create-product`, data);
      }

      router.refresh();
      /// Close Sheet
      setIsOpen(false);

      toast({
        variant: "default",
        title: toastMessage,
        description: toastMessage
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      /// Keep Sheet open on error
      setIsOpen(false);
      toast({
        variant: "destructive",
        title: "Uh oh!! Something went wrong.",
        description: "There was a problem with your request.",
      });
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SheetContent>
        <SheetHeader>
          <SheetTitle>{title}</SheetTitle>
          <SheetDescription>
            {description}
          </SheetDescription>
        </SheetHeader>

        <Form {...form}>
          <form
            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            className="space-y-8 w-full"
          >            
            <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="name"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        disabled={loading}
                        placeholder="Category name"
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />    
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="status"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Status</FormLabel>
                    <Select
                      disabled={loading}
                      onValueChange={field.onChange}
                      value={field.value}
                      defaultValue={field.value}
                    >
                      <FormControl>
                        <SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectValue
                            defaultValue={field.value}
                            placeholder="Select a status"
                          />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                      </FormControl>
                      <SelectContent>
                        <SelectItem key="Active" value="Active">Active</SelectItem>
                        <SelectItem key="Inactive" value="Inactive">Inactive</SelectItem>
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <SheetFooter>
              <Button  
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)} 
                disabled={loading} className="ml-auto" type="submit">
                {action}
              </Button>
              <SheetClose asChild>
                <Button  
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} 
                disabled={loading} className="ml-auto">
                  Cancel
                </Button>
              </SheetClose>
            </SheetFooter>
          </form>
        </Form> 
      </SheetContent>                  
    </>
  )
}



Not familiar with Shadcdn, but I believe that you arent able to close your sheet because you are not changing the boolean state variable that controls your sheet.
 <Sheet open={isOpen} onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(true)}>

The setIsOpen never gets a false value. I am thinking that when you didn't use the open prop that you werent actualy controlling for sheet with the state - and that you were using the component in the uncontrolled way.
Please try:
 <Sheet open={isOpen} onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>


Sorry. Did not work. I think we need to be able to  identify when there is error has occured and then set isOpen flag to false.

I got it to working by adding
 <Sheet open={sheetOpen} onOpenChange={() => setSheetOpen(true)}>
and removing  from the Cancel button. It also turned out I was passing wrong state values.
